# Issue with composer update

Tags: php, json, symfony, composer-php

I've tried to run "php composer.phar update" but I got this error:

```
Key extra is a duplicate in ./composer.json at line 94
ComposerHookHandler::onPreUpdate
Deprecation Notice: The Composer\Package\LinkConstraint\VersionConstraint class is deprecated, use Composer\Semver\Constraint\Constraint instead. in phar:///home/budrysl2/domains/westeros.com.pl/public_html/composer.phar/src/Composer/Package/LinkConstraint/VersionConstraint.php:17

Deprecation Notice: The Composer\Package\LinkConstraint\LinkConstraintInterface interface is deprecated, use Composer\Semver\Constraint\ConstraintInterface instead. in phar:///home/budrysl2/domains/westeros.com.pl/public_html/composer.phar/src/Composer/Package/LinkConstraint/LinkConstraintInterface.php:17

Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- The requested package mediawiki/mediawiki-codesniffer 0.5.0 is satisfiable by mediawiki/mediawiki-codesniffer[v0.5.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
Problem 2
- The requested package mediawiki/mediawiki-codesniffer 0.5.0 is satisfiable by mediawiki/mediawiki-codesniffer[v0.5.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
Problem 3
- The requested package mediawiki/mediawiki-codesniffer 0.4.0 is satisfiable by mediawiki/mediawiki-codesniffer[v0.4.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
Problem 4
- The requested package mediawiki/mediawiki-codesniffer 0.4.0 is satisfiable by mediawiki/mediawiki-codesniffer[v0.4.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
```

I use it on my MediaWiki page on westeros.com.pl

Could anybody help me?

Comment: Please post your composer.json file. Problem is in it

Comment: You can find my comoser.json file here:http://westeros.com.pl/composer.txt

Comment: Error is in your json file - you have dublicate extra sections. Composer cannot fully decode your config so it fails with error.

Comment: So should I merge those extra sections?

Comment: I think yes. This must solve your problem

Comment: Still the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Except for the duplicate `"merge-plugin"` key, your `composer.json` is correct and installs fine on my setup :

```
Generating optimized autoload files
Key merge-plugin is a duplicate in ./composer.json at line 92
Class ComposerHookHandler is not autoloadable, can not call pre-update-cmd script
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Generating optimized autoload files
$
```

Maybe there was a problem in one of the package dependencies before ?

Comment: I'm not sure about issue with dependencies before? How to check that? How to update them?

Comment: if you run `composer update` now on your file it should just work